# How do I sum only certain elements from an array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to sum only the elements from the array `out` that have a value less than 0.49, but I'm not sure how to implement a *filter* for that criteria. Here is what I have so far:

```
def outcome(surveys,voters):
    out = np.random.random((surveys,voters))
    rep = [0]*surveys
    for i in range(0,surveys):
        rep[i] = sum(out[i,:])
    return rep
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the array in your code?

Comment: numpy.random.random((x,y)) returns an x by y array of random numbers from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `comparison` directly on the array, that will return a boolean or mask array useful to access the interesting part of the array, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html.

in other words,

```
def outcome(surveys,voters):
    out = np.random.random((surveys,voters))
    rep = [0]*surveys
    for i in range(0,surveys):
        rep[i] = sum(out[i,out[i,:]<0.49])
    return rep
```

Comment: This will sum only those larger than 0.49 rather than only those less. And while it works in principle, iterating `out` in python is unneccesary and by far slower than using the built in functionality of numpy

Answer (score 3):

I would use masked arrays and then just sum along the axis:

```
out = np.ma.masked_greater_equal(np.random.random((surveys,voters)), 0.49)
rep = out.sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = [0.25, 0.1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.1, 0.9]
>>> sum(i for i in l if i < 0.49)
0.44999999999999996
```

Alternatively

```
>>> l = [0.25, 0.1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.1, 0.9]
>>> sum(filter(lambda x: x < 0.49, l))
0.44999999999999996
```